# Is it possible to combine a Qt engine with a Windows Phone native UI (XAML-based)?

Tags: qt, windows-phone-8.1, winrt-xaml

Qt 5 modues we would like to use:

- Qt Core, signals and slots
- Qt Network
- Qt SQL

Target Platform is Windows Phone 8.1.

Potential conflicts:

- Event loop
- Graphical User Interface (while no UI should be drawn by Qt)

Comment: Have you seen this? http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/winrt-support.html

Comment: Sure I know that Qt5 supports WinRT, but it does no tell me how to combine it with a XAML-based UI. The demos I have seen so far are QtQuick-based.